# How do you test whether a Ruby destructor will be called?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, destructor

I have created a class which I want to hang on to a file descriptor and close it when the instance is GC-ed.

I created a class that looks something like this:

```
class DataWriter
  def initialize(file)
    # open file
    @file = File.open(file, 'wb')
    # create destructor
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, self.class.finalize(@file))
  end

  # write
  def write(line)
    @file.puts(line)
    @file.flush
  end

  # close file descriptor, note, important that it is a class method
  def self.finalize(file)
    proc { file.close; p "file closed"; p file.inspect}
  end
end
```

I then tried to test the destructor method like so:

```
RSpec.describe DataWriter do
  context 'it should call its destructor' do
    it 'calls the destructor' do
      data_writer = DataWriter.new('/tmp/example.txt')
      expect(DataWriter).to receive(:finalize)
      data_writer = nil
      GC.start
    end
  end
end
```

When running this test, even though the "file closed" is printed along with the file.inspect, the test fails with the following output:

```
1) DataWriter it should call its destructor calls the destructor
     Failure/Error: expect(DataWriter).to receive(:finalize)

       (DataWriter (class)).finalize(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/utils/data_writer_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Upvote because you got me learning about garbage collection and finalization in ruby :D

Comment: @GavinMiller I just learnt about it too, just came back to ruby after a foray into C++ land so I naturally started looking for a destructor, and learnt that they're a little unusual in ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`finalize` is called in `initialize`, returns the proc, and is never called again, so you can't expect it to be called at finalization time. It's the *proc* that's called when the instance is finalized. To check that, have the proc call a method instead of doing the work itself. This passes:

```
class DataWriter
  # initialize and write same as above

  def self.finalize(file)
    proc { actually_finalize file }
  end

  def self.actually_finalize(file)
    file.close
  end

end

RSpec.describe DataWriter do
  context 'it should call its destructor' do
    it 'calls the destructor' do
      data_writer = DataWriter.new('/tmp/example.txt')
      expect(DataWriter).to receive(:actually_finalize)
      data_writer = nil
      GC.start
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that `GC.start` is just a *hint* that the GC *might* run now, it is not guaranteed that the GC *will* actually run. And even if it runs, there is no guarantee *which* objects it will collect. For example, if it is a realtime GC, it might have a hard limit on how long it is allowed to run and so it might simply not get around to collecting all orphaned objects. So, there are all sorts of reasons this test might fail even if the finalizer works perfectly.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I suspected that was the case. Do you have any docs to read up more about the ruby GC?

Answer (score 1):

> even though the "file closed" is printed along with the file.inspect, the test fails with the following output

I threw your code into a single file and ran it. It appears that the finalize code isn't being cleaned up until rspec exits given the output I'm receiving:

```
Failures:
F

  1) DataWriter it should call its destructor calls the destructor
     Failure/Error: expect(DataWriter).to receive(:finalize)

       (DataWriter (class)).finalize(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # /scratch/data_writer.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01066 seconds (files took 0.16847 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec /scratch/data_writer.rb:25 # DataWriter it should call its destructor calls the destructor

"file closed"
"#<File:/tmp/example.txt (closed)>"
```

---

<del>As to the why of it, I can't tell right now.</del> [Dave is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217870/33226) you're asserting on something that's already happened, so your test is never going to pass. You can observe this by changing your test to:

```
 it 'calls the destructor' do
   expect(DataWriter).to receive(:finalize).and_call_original
   data_writer = DataWriter.new('/tmp/example.txt')
   data_writer = nil
   GC.start
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should not rely on the finalizer to run exactly when GC runs. They will run, eventually. But perhaps only when the Process finishes. As far as I can tell this is also dependent on the Ruby implementation and the GC implementation.
1.8 has different behavior than 1.9+, Rubinius and JRuby might be different as well.

Making sure that a resource is released can be achieved by a block, which will also take care that the resource is released as soon as not needed anymore.

Multiple APIs have the same style in Ruby:

```
File.open('thing.txt', 'wb') do |file| # file is passed to block
                                       # do something with file
end                                    # file will be closed when block ends
```

Instead of doing this (as you showed in your gist)

```
(1..100_000).each do |i|
  File.open(filename, 'ab') do |file|
    file.puts "line: #{i}"
  end
end
```

I'd do it this way:

```
File.open(filename, 'wb') do |file|
  (1..100_000).each do |i|
    file.puts "line: #{i}"
  end
end
```

Comment: How should I do that with the style of code I have now? I feel that holding onto the filename and opening it every time I want to write would be much more inefficient than just holding onto the file descriptor once and then using it until I discard my class. (I will shamefully admit that I haven't actually profiled this yet, but was just my default style of writing.)
In addition, this is only a problem for testing, for my code, I only care that things get cleaned up. For my test I care about when.

Comment: @MikeH-R i added a small sample.

Relying on finalizers will cause troubles because it's not really defined when it will run.

Comment: I think you're missing what I'm saying, I made [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mijoharas/f7968a546d4681ab7f5a83115f5bf2d7) to show what I mean, the first approach is 9 times slower.

Comment: I understand what you mean but don't understand why you do it this way. Check my edit.
And unless you can show me a source that says that finalizers are run instantly and in a consistent manner across implementations then i dont understand why you think that its a good solution to rely on them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer pascal, that is the correct and obvious way to write a lot of sequential data to a file (and what I would use 90% of the time), but that does not fit the semantics of what I am currently trying to do. I don't particularly need the finalizer to be run instantly (only eventually, to ensure fd's aren't being leaked), the only time I care about the timing of when they are being run is when unit testing.

Comment: Essentially, your solution assumes that I can do all of my writing within a block, which doesn't make sense for my use case.

Comment: GC only runs once in a while, when Ruby deems it necessary. So files might stay open until the end of the process or until GC runs. Which also means that they might not be flushed.

Comment: True, notice my example code includes a flush after a write. Note that I am trading off holding onto an extra fd for a while for write performance. Again, I agree that your solution is simpler, and what should be picked most of the time, but does not offer the same trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my working solution below, bit I have not ran this code.

```
RSpec.describe DataWriter do
  context 'it should call its destructor' do
    it 'calls the destructor' do

      # creating pipe for IPC to get result from child process
      # after it garbaged
      # http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe
      rd, wr = IO.pipe

      # forking 
      # https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html#method-c-fork
      if fork      
        wr.close
        called = rd.read
        Process.wait
        expect(called).to eq('/tmp/example.txt')
        rd.close
      else
        rd.close
      # overriding DataWriter.actually_finalize(file)
        DataWriter.singleton_class.class_eval do
          define_method(:actually_finalize) do |arg|
            wr.write arg
            wr.close
          end
        end

        data_writer = DataWriter.new('/tmp/example.txt')
        data_writer = nil
        GC.start
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The main thing is I catch that GC.start call performs real work exactly when exiting from process. I have tried blocks and threads but in my case (ruby 2.2.4p230 @ Ubuntu x86_64) it works only when a process finished.

I suggest, that there may exist a better way to get results from child process, but I used inter-process communication (IPC).

And I have not got result with building the rspec expectation on destructor method call in form like `expect(DataWriter).to receive(:actually_finalize).with('/tmp/example.txt')` - I don't know why, but I suppose that wrappers created by Rspec have been garbaged or infringed before calling of destructor of a class.

Hope this helps!